# Setting a route depending on a String in the URL with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am pretty new to Symfony.

I need to check if an URL contains a certain word, which can be in any order, and if it has, it will be redirected to a certain page.

For example `www.example.com/mystring/,  www.example.com/content/mystring or www.example.com/001/content/mystring/` should redirect you to www.example.com/mystring because it contains `mystring` in the URL

This could be easy:

```
$routes->add('mystring', '/mystring/')
    ->controller([MyStringController::class, 'show'])
;

$routes->add('mystring', '{number}/{content}/mystring')
    ->controller([MyStringController::class, 'show'])
;
```

Etc etc the problem is that `mystring` could be anywhere in the URL.

I already have a workaround in the controller that will redirect you if the string, however I would like a clean solution in the Routing file.

So the question is:

Is there any way to set a route depending if a URL contains certain string that can be anywhere and in any order?

Comment: What you are asking is the purpose of a routing system. You should add requirements to your parameters to avoid conflict. For example, your number parameters should have the \d+ requirements.
And remember, the first route matching is always used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, yes. A route placeholder usually isn't allowed to contain a `/`, because it makes things more difficult. However, there are ways to allow it. BUT, there are other problems arising, unless that additional magic string always takes priority over anything else that happens.

To allow a slash inside a placeholder, this is possible with this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

so essentially to add a slash, you'd have a route with

`'/{url}'`, and requirement `'url' => '.+'`

now, just a `'.+'` is not enough for your purpose though. I'm not absolutely certain about escaping in this case, but it would probably be something like

```
'url' => '.*\bmystring\b.*'
```

if `\b` is allowed, this means it's a word boundary (which is probably what you want).

otherwise `'(.+/)*mystring(.+/|$)+'` should do the trick

Also, you shouldn't name multiple routes the same ... also, this kind of route definition won't give you the other placeholders you have ...

If your special route should extend only existing routes, though, you should probably find a way to cycle through existing routes and add your magic string. But that's a different question ;o)